# XmlHttpRequest status 0 even when the call to service succeeded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wcf, xmlhttprequest

I call to `Wcf Service` via `Jquery`(JS), after a long time of trying it works.

The call to service is as follows:

```
function CallService() {   
    var request = { userName: "aaa", password: "123" };
    var jsondata = JSON.stringify(request);   
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST", //GET or POST or PUT or DELETE verb
        url: "http://localhost:xxxx/Service1.svc/GetUser", // Location of the service
        data: jsondata, //Data sent to server
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // content type sent to server
        dataType: "json", //Expected data format from server
        processdata: true, //True or False
        crossDomain: true, //True or False
        success: function (result) {
            alert('success');
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert('completed');
        },
        error: function (xhr, status, message) {
            alert('error with status - ' + xhr.status);
        }
    });  
}
```

I put BreakPoint in GetUser function that is in service and when I call the function CallService I go to the BreakPoint of Service (which means it works!).

Service function works great and returns the correct data, but to Jquery I get the Error function with **status 0**.

In addition, in the console I see a red error:(Not generally understood as an error)

```
POST http://localhost:xxx/Service1.svc/GetUser
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was that in `User` object I had `DateTime`.

When I turned it to `String` it **worked**.

Answer (score 1):

It could be that you're making a cross-domain request. Note that the same host name with different ports are considered different domain. For example: `http://localhost:20` and `http://localhost:40` are considered different domains.

In your case, it could be that your browser **supports CORS** and therefore requests to a different domain are still sent. That's why when you debug on server side you see it works, but when the browser receives response from the server, the response is discarded and an error is raised because of missing `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header from the response or having the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header but with a value different than your domain.

Comment: I used the suggestion of this site:  [suggestion](http://blog.weareon.net/calling-wcf-rest-service-from-jquery-causes-405-method-not-allowed/). Here you can see that I have `HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom: did you check that you're making a cross domain request?

Comment: I do cross domain request but the website above has given a solution, it was supposed to work, right?

Comment: @Hodaya Shalom: yes, it should work for **browsers supporting CORS**. Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, the service started to work me (ie reach the breakpoint) only after I did it.